# In linear algebra when solving an equation is there a reason we solve it in terms of the last variable or is it an arbitrary decision?

Tags: linear-algebra

So if we had a set of linear equations like x + y + z = 5 and x + y + 2z = 10 why do we always parameterize the solution in terms of z? Is it just an arbitrary choice because it's the last variable? And are there situations where it would make more sense to specifically choose a variable to parameterize around?

Like looking through this solution set, every time it's the last variable that the equation is solved around. I figure it's completely arbitrary but I want to make sure.
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Vectors_in_Space/Solutions

Comment: It is a rather widely used agreement...but by no means is that a must. Yet I've met quite a few teachers that make it compulsory to solve in terms of the last variables ALWAYS...and there seems to be a pretty simple reason for this: that way it is very simple to check the answers in a quiz or exam. If that is left arbitrary then the answers, though equivalent and exactly the same (if done correctly) can look pretty different...

Comment: That's why I wonder if it's ever beneficial to solve in terms of another variable, maybe the solution set will be more elegant, or less computationally difficult to solve.

Comment: Maybe it will be...but in quizzes and exams it is always preferable to make it simple to check. If you're doing a computer program then you could choose whatever you like with respect to some standards that are important to you...

Answer (score 1):

> why do we always parameterize the solution in terms of z? Is it just an arbitrary choice because it's the last variable?

This is not true, presumably it is how it is taught in your region, but there is no particular reason to do so. You could label the variable what you like, e.g if we had a solution to some equations $(11+\frac{z}{4\pi},\frac{z+12\pi}{2\pi},\frac{z}{\pi})$, it is also perfectly valid to say $z=4\pi t$ then we get $(11+t,2t+6,4t)$, which you can adapt however you like to get a nicer form of the solution(purely aesthetic). Since $z$ was arbitrary, $t$ is arbitrary, so these solutions are identical.

> And are there situations where it would make more sense to specifically choose a variable to parameterize around?

Again, this is purely notational, you gain no new insight by choosing which variable to parameterise.